# compile multiple cuda files (that have dynamic parallelism) and MPI code

Tags: c, makefile, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

I have a bunch of .cu files that use dynamic parallelism (a.cu, b.cu, c.cu.., e.cu, f.cu), and a main.c file that uses MPI to call functions from a.cu on multiple nodes. I'm trying to write a make file to compile the executable, but I keep facing the following errors:

```
cudafiles.o: In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_66_tmpxft_00001a84_00000000_17_cuda_device_runtime_compute_61_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37':
link.stub:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_66_tmpxft_00001a84_00000000_17_cuda_device_runtime_compute_61_cpp1_ii_8b1a5d37'
```

Here is my makefile:

```
INCFILES=-I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include -I/opt/mpi/mvapich2-gnu/2.2/include -I./
LIBFILES=-L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -L/opt/mpi/mvapich2-gnu/2.2/lib
LIBS=-lcudart -lcudadevrt -lcublas_device -lmpi 
ARCH=-gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60
NVCC=nvcc -ccbin g++


default: all

all: clean final.o

io.o: io.cpp
        g++ -c -std=c++11  io.cpp 


final.o: io.o a.cu b.cu c.cu d.cu e.cu f.cu main.cpp
        $(NVCC) -std=c++11 $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES) $(LIBS) -g -G -Xptxas -v -dc $(ARCH) a.cu b.cu c.cu d.cu e.cu f.cu
        $(NVCC) -std=c++11 $(ARCH) $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES) $(LIBS) -rdc=true -dlink a.o b.o c.o d.o e.o f.o io.o -o cudafiles.o
        mpicxx -O3 $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES) -c main.cpp -o main.o
        mpicxx $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES) $(LIBS) cudafiles.o a.o b.o c.o d.o e.o f.o io.o main.o -o exec

clean:
        rm -rf *.o exec
```

Comment: 1. add `-dlink` to your 2nd `(NVCC)` line.  2. change `main.c` to `main.cpp`, both the filename itself as well as all references in the makefile.  3. switch from `mpicc` to `mpicxx`  Note that you don't show `g.o` getting built anywhere,  and you don't show `io.o` getting used anywhere, so I'm guessing this not really the makefile you are using.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I've made the edits you suggested (see edited file above). Now, I get the following errors: "undefined reference to cudaFree, cudaSetDevice")

Comment: add `-lcudart` to `LIBS`

Comment: Thanks Robert. Even after adding -lcudart to libs, I get linking errors (as shown above). Thanks for helping again!

Comment: 1. define your `LIBS` variable like this: `LIBS=-lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -lmpi -lcudart` 2. In your final link step, move the `$(LIBS)` reference to the end of the line, like so: `mpicxx $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES)  cudafiles.o a.o b.o c.o d.o e.o f.o io.o main.o -o exec $(LIBS)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The original problem reported was an undefined reference to `main`.  This was arising from this line in the `Makefile`:

   ```
   $(NVCC) -std=c++11 $(ARCH) $(INCFILES) $(LIBFILES) $(LIBS) -rdc=true a.o b.o c.o d.o e.o f.o io.o -o cudafiles.o
   ```

   As constructed, this actually instructs `nvcc` to perform full/final linking.  However the intent of this line was to perform the device-link step only, required when compiling with `-rdc=true` or `-dc`, and when not performing the final link with `nvcc`.  In this case, the final link was being performed by `mpicc`/`mpicxx`.  To perform the device-link step only, we need to specify `-dlink`.  Without that switch, `nvcc` expects to do final linking, but fails because none of the supplied objects contain a `main` function.  The correct solution, since we have no intent to do final link at this point, is to use the `-dlink` switch.
2. I also suggested converting everything to C++ style linking, since `nvcc` links that way.  It might be possible to sort out a C-style link with a C++-style link, but this just seems troublesome to me.  Therefore I suggested converting the only `.c` file (`main.c`) to a `.cpp` file, and convert from `mpicc` to `mpicxx`
3. The next problem that arose was undefined references to e.g. `cudaSetDevice()` and `cudaFree()`.  These are part of the CUDA runtime API library ("libcudart").  When performing final link with `nvcc`, these are linked automatically.  But since final link is being performed by `mpicxx` (basically a wrapper on `g++`), it's necessary to call out the link against that library specifically with `-lcudart`.
4. Finally, the remaining problem was a link-order problem.  In a nutshell, link dependencies need to be satisfied from left to right in the linker command line.  Different compilers are more or less picky about this.  The final reordering changes were to specify the libraries to link against in the correct order, and also to specify these libraries at the end of the link command line, so that any dependencies on these libraries, to their left in the link command line, are satisfied.